# Using a Coherence NamedCache -- How much overhead is there?

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, spring-batch, oracle-coherence

Currently I am trying to figure out the best way to retrieve and save data.

I am working on a spring batch program with masters and slaves, and I was iterating through some data and saving into a hashmap. Originally I was just saving data into a hashmap, thinking I would never need it again, but it turns out I will need some of it in a later step.

It would be nice if I could just simply replace this hashmap with a namedcache. And use it in the step I created it in, and the following steps as well. However i'm worried it will cause excess overhead.

Should I keep the hashmap, and eventually iterate it into the cache for using later? Or should I just simply replace this hashmap with a namedcache?

Answer (score 1):

I've used EhCache before in batch jobs to store static data (countries, billing codes, etc).  It's not an unusual paradigm and works very well.